# integrating barcode scanner into php application?

Tags: php

We have been developing web application in php.
We need barcode scanner to be integrated into our application.

Our application is divided into two modules, users and merchant.

When user comes and scans the card, merchant should be identified the user by barcode number. Admin will give barcode number and that is being sent to the card manufacturer and the number will be assigned to the magnetic stripe.

As i know scanner can acts as a key board, can you please tell the method to integrate barcode scanner into this php web based application?

Answer (score 92):

PHP can be easily utilized for reading bar codes printed on paper documents. Connecting manual barcode reader to the computer via USB significantly extends usability of PHP (or any other web programming language) into tasks involving document and product management, like finding a book records in the database or listing all bills for a particular customer.

Following sections briefly describe process of connecting and using manual bar code reader with PHP.

> The usage of bar code scanners described in this article are in the
>   same way applicable to any web programming language, such as ASP,
>   Python or Perl. This article uses only PHP since all tests have been
>   done with PHP applications.

**What is a bar code reader (scanner)**

Bar code reader is a hardware pluggable into computer that sends decoded bar code strings into computer. The trick is to know how to catch that received string. With PHP (and any other web programming language) the string will be placed into focused input HTML element in browser. Thus to catch received bar code string, following must be done:

just before reading the bar code, proper input element, such as INPUT TEXT FIELD must be focused (mouse cursor is inside of the input field).
once focused, start reading the code
when the code is recognized (bar code reader usually shortly beeps), it is send to the focused input field. By default, most of bar code readers will append extra special character to decoded bar code string called CRLF (ENTER). For example, if decoded bar code is "12345AB", then computer will receive "12345AB<kbd>ENTER</kbd>". Appended character <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (or <kbd>CRLF</kbd>) emulates pressing the key ENTER causing instant submission of the HTML form:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
    <input name="documentID" onmouseover="this.focus();" type="text">
</form>
```

**Choosing the right bar code scanner**

When choosing bar code reader, one should consider what types of bar codes will be read with it. Some bar codes allow only numbers, others will not have checksum, some bar codes are difficult to print with inkjet printers, some barcode readers have narrow reading pane and cannot read for example barcodes with length over 10 cm. Most of barcode readers support common barcodes, such as EAN8, EAN13, CODE 39, Interleaved 2/5, Code 128 etc.

For office purposes, the most suitable barcodes seem to be those supporting full range of alphanumeric characters, which might be:

- code 39 - supports 0-9, uppercased A-Z, and few special characters (dash, comma, space, $, /, +, %, *)
- code 128 - supports 0-9, a-z, A-Z and other extended characters

Other important things to note:

- make sure all standard barcodes are supported, at least CODE39, CODE128, Interleaved25, EAN8, EAN13, PDF417, QRCODE.
- use only standard USB plugin cables. RS232 interfaces are meant for industrial usage, rather than connecting to single PC.
- the cable should be long enough, at least 1.5 m - the longer the better.
- bar code reader plugged into computer should not require other power supply - it should power up simply by connecting to PC via USB.
- if you also need to print bar code into generated PDF documents, you can use TCPDF open source library that supports most of common 2D bar codes.

**Installing scanner drivers**

Installing manual bar code reader requires installing drivers for your particular operating system and should be normally supplied with purchased bar code reader.

Once installed and ready, bar code reader turns on signal LED light. Reading the barcode starts with pressing button for reading.

**Scanning the barcode - how does it work?**

**STEP 1** - Focused input field ready for receiving character stream from bar code scanner:

[image: step 1]

**STEP 2** - Received barcode string from bar code scanner is immediatelly submitted for search into database, which creates nice "automated" effect:

[image: step 2]

**STEP 3** - Results returned after searching the database with submitted bar code:

[image: step 3]

**Conclusion**

It seems, that utilization of PHP (and actually any web programming language) for scanning the bar codes has been quite overlooked so far. However, with natural support of emulated keypress (ENTER/CRLF) it is very easy to automate collecting & processing recognized bar code strings via simple HTML (GUI) fomular.

The key is to understand, that recognized bar code string is instantly sent to the focused HTML element, such as INPUT text field with appended trailing character ASCII 13 (=ENTER/CRLF, configurable option), which instantly sends input text field with populated received barcode as a HTML formular to any other script for further processing.

[Reference: http://www.synet.sk/php/en/280-barcode-reader-scanner-in-php](http://www.synet.sk/php/en/280-barcode-reader-scanner-in-php)

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: i know the question is a bit old. But i have a related question. I already develop a little php application with a physical barcode scanner. But now i like to expand it by using mobile phones as scanners and store the scanned data on the phone. Do you have any suggestion which android barcode application i could use which scans and stores the data which i can then import into my php application?

Comment: Reference link explains exactly the same...Thanks to Lubos Dzurik (The author)for such a nice article and to you too. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use AJAX for that. Whenever you scan a barcode, your scanner will act as if it is a keyboard typing into your `input type="text"` components. With JavaScript, capture the corresponding event, and send HTTP REQUEST and process responses accordingly.

Comment: Does it act like a keyboard input device when it is connected via wifi/bluetooth?

Answer (score 3):

I've been using something like this. Just set up a simple HTML page with an textinput. Make sure that the textinput always has focus. When you scan a barcode with your barcode scanner you will receive the code and after that a 'enter'. Realy simple then; just capture the incoming keystrokes and when the 'enter' comes in you can use AJAX to handle your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Bluetooth, Use twedge on windows and getblue app on android, they also have a few videos of it. It's made by TEC-IT. I've got it to work by setting the interface option to bluetooth server in TWedge and setting the output setting in getblue to Bluetooth client and selecting my computer from the Bluetooth devices list. Make sure your computer and phone is paired. Also to get the barcode as input set the action setting in TWedge to Keyboard Wedge. This will allow for you to first click the input text box on said form, then scan said product with your phone and wait a sec for the barcode number to be put into the text box. Using this method requires no php that doesn't already exist in your current form processing, just process the text box as usual and viola your phone scans bar codes, sends them to your pc via Bluetooth wirelessly, your computer inserts the barcode into whatever text field is selected in any application or website. Hope this helps.