# Barcode Scanner to redirect to url on scan

Tags: javascript, php, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I have a USB barcode scanner that pastes data from the barcodes it scans. Is it possible to scan a barcode and redirect from the current browser and into a page based on the scanned information? This would be using php, html, and js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465839/integrating-barcode-scanner-into-php-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps.

```
<h3>Barcode</h3>
<textarea class="bcode" name="barcode"></textarea>
<span class="action"></span>
```

Some js to handle the action

```
$(function() {
  $('.bcode').on('paste',function(){
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      //now do something with the paste data
      window.location = "https://www.google.se/search?q=" + _this.value;
    },1000);
  });
});
```

Test the code here
https://codepen.io/mbzbugsy/pen/EmZPYP

Comment: That looks very promising, but did not seem to work on the example. It scans properly, but the data only fills the form, it doesn't actually redirect

Comment: I would guess your form is being filled out mimicking keyboard inputs rather than pasting. As such you might want to tweak the above code to bind to `keyup` instead and have the timeout saved into a variable so any preceding entries can be cancelled.

Comment: Something like this should do the trick:
```$(function() {
    var _timer = null;

    $('.bcode').on('keyup', function() {
        var _this = this;
        if (_timer !== null) clearTimeout(_timer);
        _timer = setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = "https://www.google.se/search?q=" + _this.value;
        }, 500);
    });
});```

Comment: Yes, that was just a concept. You can do this many ways. I used the paste event because I thought the USB barcode scanner would paste the code. Codepen doesn't allow url redirects. To test the code fully you need to try it somewhere else.